# Is there any replacement module for token actions and token starter modules in D7?

Tags: 7, updating, tokens

I am using TokenActions and TokenStarter modules in my one of the project which is in D6.

Now, I have planned to upgrade it into D7.

**I have found the D7 version of Tokens module but I didn't find Tokens Actions and Token Starter in that module.**

Is that modules are removed are is it still existing in some other names?

I had googled a lot. But I didn't find anything really useful...

Coudl you guys help me out of this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From Dave..Mainter of token module... (As Received)**

The Token Actions module has been replaced by the actions provided by core that support tokens. Use the follow button on http://drupal.org/node/1902294 to track progress for migrating those deprecated actions to system-provided ones automatically.

The Token starter is not an actual module that is intended to be used. It's just an example of how you make new tokens. It was deprecated by the token example module in http://drupal.org/project/examples. You should instead make a custom module with a good name for your custom tokens, rather than re-using the token starter module.